# How to print page as PDF using PDF Creator of a Google Chrome page not in image format?

Tags: google-chrome, pdfcreator

Well, when I print some pages of websites on my Firefox or Internet Explorer using PDF Creator printer, in the result PDF I can select text and copy/paste it as a common text...

But why in Chrome all PDF are printed as images???? I cannot select PDF's texts...

How can I print normally pages as text PDFs on Google Chrome???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that by default when Chrome sends the rendered page to the printer, it's rasterizing everything before sending it to the print spooler.  By the time the PDF creator gets the data, the damage has already been done.

I'm running Chrome Beta 21.0.1180.57 on Windows, and there are 2 workarounds:

1. From Chrome's Print Dialog, click the `Change...` button in the `Destination` category.  One of the options under `Local Destinations` should be `Save as PDF`.  Chrome will then render a PDF using an internal PDF creator that will give you a PDF with selectable text and embedded fonts.
2. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or the `Print using system dialog...` link from Chrome's print dialog.  If you print to your PDF creator from there, it will send text and images to the print spooler and you end up with a PDF with embedded text.  I'm not sure why the behavior is different between the 2 dialogs.

Comment: Man, It solved my problem :) As I could see, the second solution generates a PDF that appears to be in lower quality...